# my file can't find my function in the class

Tags: php

For some weird reason, my file can't seem to find a function filterAll in my class Post. It can find any other function in the class. But now it can't find any new ones I make at all.

This is where I summon it

```
$arrayUser = array();
$arrayMood = array();

$filter = new Post();
$statementFilter = $filter->getAll();

while ($row = $statementFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $arrayUser[] = $row['username'];
    $arrayMood[]= $row['moods'];
}
```

this is the function

```
class Post{ 
    public function getAll()
    {
        $conn = db::getInstance();

        $statementFilter = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM postmoodi INNER JOIN moods ON postmoodi.moodID = moods.moodID INNER JOIN users ON postmoodi.userID = users.userID");
        $statementFilter -> execute(array());
        $statementFilter->fetch();

        return $statementFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$statementFilter->fetch()` already fetches a record. If there's no more records next call to `$statementFilter->fetch()` returns some falsy value.

Comment: And if method will be really not found - you will get a fatal error and optionally a blank screen.

Comment: put phpstorm says it can't find the function.